# CDN video caching duration

Tags: cache, cdn, video, video-streaming, video-hosting

Are there any standards about for how long (days, weeks) do CDNs cache video content?

[This other answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/469048/caching-video-content-on-cdn) suggested that it is only for a short period of time (e.g. 1 day) but that information is almost a decade old by now. For regular (non-video) content, there are cache settings.

How is it for video content? Where can I find more information about this (I could not find it on the websites of some CDN providers).

PS: I am **not** asking for product suggestions.

Comment: if you really want to have a guaranteed answer open a ticket on the vendor

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have to do that. But if I were to be satisfied with an approximate answer?

Comment: products suggestions are not on topic. however without specific knowledge what plan you use it will nearly impossible to answer